# Winform C# Taborder of DataGridView only in first row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tab-ordering

When I set `this.grv.TabStop = true` (grv's type is DataGridView) , taborder effect with each cell in DataGridView. I want tab to DataGridView only stop in first row of list. How can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you! But I want answer in winform case.

Comment: You could simply use its Enter event to select the first row.  But do consider what should happen when the user uses the mouse to change the focus.  Making the mouse work drastically different from the keyboard is never not a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [DataGridView.StandardTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.standardtab(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the TAB key moves the focus to
>   the next control in the tab order rather than moving focus to the next
>   cell in the control.